# How to zip a file and save it in another directory

Tags: shell, zip

How can I zip a file and save it in another directory using the command line? I have no space left in directory (100% full).

Comment: You don't do that on PuTTY. PuTTY is just the tool you use to access the "other" computer; so it is not a PuTTY question, but (maybe) a shell one.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423679/specify-destination-directory-for-zip-command-output-the-zip-file-that-is-cre

Answer (score 28):

```
zip -r  /path/to/save/destination_folder.zip /path/to/folder
```

- /path/to/folder  - path to your source folder
- /path/to/save/destination_folder.zip - path to destination zip-file
- r - recurse into directories

Also you can just type `zip` in putty command prompt to get help information

Please, notice I wrote information for *nix systems. For Win it could be differ.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking at the man pages for tar, we can set the output file with -f

I usually use something of the form:

`tar -a -cf filename.tar.bz2 input_fname.txt`

Then you can specify your filepath as part of your filename to output. 
For example `/mnt/drive_1/output.tar.bz2` or `../../output.tgz` would work as a filename. Then you would end up with your compressed file at that place.

Arguments:

- a: auto compress: Uses your given file type to figure out what to do.
- c: compress: Tells it to compress instead of decompressing
- f: set a file name: allows you to specify your file and file path. You can also give relative path names as well.

I'm hoping that tar compression just puts everything at the output file and doesn't do anything in your directory. Try it and see if it works though.

Comment: While I gave examples with tar.bz2 and tgz, it will work with the zip extension as well.

Comment: 'c' is not the compression option, it is the "create" option. zip is not supported by GNU tar. zip is both an archiver and a compression format.

Comment: I don't know if we have different versions of tar, but in my man pages, under the -a, --auto-compress option, it says that it ignore things like -j if it doesn't work with the file extension. 

In my man pages for creating a new archive with the zip format: 
    "tar -a -cf archive.zip source.c source.h
creates a new archive with zip format,"

along with some other features. 

You are right that it is to create an archive and not compress one though.

Comment: I was going by [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#auto_002dcompress)

Comment: When I run "tar -a -cf archive.zip source.c source.h" with GNU tar I get an uncompressed tar archive, not a zip archive.

Comment: I'm running GNU tar 1.27.1, but I must have done something to it because it has a note in the man pages saying that my implementation of it can extract and create from zip, rar, and a whole bunch of other extra formats. I just checked on my other slightly more vanilla machine, and it doesn't have it.

Comment: I will pay you $$ for your tar implementation :)

Comment: We should probably not spam the original poster too much more. hehe... Really, all I can say is that I'm running on a heavily configured arch linux, but I don't think I touched tar.

Comment: the question is about zip

Comment: And as noted in the comments above, my implementation of tar can zip files.